# proof of $\sin(420º+\alpha) + \cos(60º+\alpha) = \sin(90º-\alpha)$?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was trying to proof this using the right side, and I'm aware that $\cos (60 + \alpha) + \cos(60 + \alpha)$ it's what I'm really looking for but I can't find a way to proof it.

\begin{align}
\sin (90º-\alpha) &= \sin(90º) \cos(\alpha) - \cos(90º)\sin(\alpha) \\
\sin (90º-\alpha) &= 1 \cos(\alpha) - 0\sin(\alpha) \\
\sin (90º-\alpha) &= \cos(\alpha)
\end{align}

and here I'm stuck. How could $\underbrace{ \cos(\alpha) }_\text{this}$ be equal to $\underbrace{\sin(420º+\alpha) + \cos(60º+\alpha)}_\text{this}$ ?

Comment: Are you trying to prove an identity or are you trying to solve an equation?  Which is it?  Your subject line says "proof", and your tags say "proof", but your first sentence says "solve". $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to proof.

Comment: If $\alpha=0$ then $\sin(420^\circ+\alpha) + \cos(60^\circ+\alpha) = \dfrac{1+\sqrt 3} 2 $ but $\cos\alpha=1 \ne \dfrac{1+\sqrt3}2$.  So the proposed identity is false.  On the other hand, if you're trying to solve an equation for $\alpha$, that can be done. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation is not true for $\alpha = 0$. Since $sin(420+\alpha)= sin (360 + 60 +\alpha) = sin (60 + \alpha)$ So $sin (60) + cos (60) \neq 1$!